# How to remove scroll downs when an HTML code is embeded in Google Sites

Tags: html, mobile, accordion, device

I have a Google sites where I include an accordion. However, on a mobile device the HTML box used for accordion has a fixed height and due to this (I guess) the look is terrible.

How can I add an accordion on a Google site while keeping the site mobile device friendly?